# IEnumerable vs IQueryable vs List

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, linq

He investigado el uso de `IEnumerable` e `IQueryable` pero a pesar de haber leído diferentes artículos no me queda claro en qué situaciones debería implementarse el uno o el otro.

Siempre he usado `List<>` para el uso de diferentes tipos de listas, incluidas las listas que me trae como resultado la ejecución de un query.

Para ejemplificar mi duda mostraré algo de código, espero logre aclarar mi punto.

Sin hacer uso de Entity Framework, haciendo todo a mano crearía un método como el siguiente para realizar una consulta básica a una tabla:

```
public List<PersonaEN> ObtenerPersona()
{
    MySqlConnection conn = null;
            
    try
    {
        conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["K2"].ConnectionString);
        //conn.Open(); --> No es necesario abrir la conexion.
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand() { Connection = conn, CommandText = "SELECT * FROM cp_pers", CommandType = CommandType.Text };
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command); //Adapta el commando a lo que necesita MySQL para interpretarlo.
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //Tipo de objeto .NET
        adapter.Fill(dt); //Fill coger lo que retorno la consulta en el adapter y se los pasa al dt.
        listPersona = (from t in dt.AsEnumerable()
                       select new PersonaEN()
                       {
                           Documento = t.Field<int>("Docum"),
                           PrimerNombre = t.Field<string>("prnom"),
                           SegundoNombre = t.Field<string>("sgnom"),
                           PrimerApellido = t.Field<string>("prape"),
                           SegundoApellido = t.Field<string>("sgape"),
                           FechaNacimiento = t.Field<DateTime>("fechan"),
                           Edad = t.Field<int>("edad"),
                           CodigoDireccion = t.Field<Int32?>("codDi") ?? 0
                       }).ToList();
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }    
    finally
    {
        if (conn != null && conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    return listPersona;
}
```

Y haciendo uso de Entity Framework tendría este método que haría lo mismo que el anterior:

```
public List<PERSONA> ObtenerPersona()
{
    return context.PERSONA.ToList();
}
```

En ambos casos, como pueden observar, devuelvo una lista de la entidad *PersonaEN*. Hasta ahora no he tenido problemas con esto, puedo iterar la lista, puedo implementar LINQ, sin embargo he visto que la mayoría de desarrollos más profesionales o de personas con mayor experiencia retornan `IEnumerable` vs `IQueryable`.

Comment: Hola, seria bueno que marcaras como aceptada la respuesta que te fue util(si asi lo consideras, claro) y que dieras tu voto positivo a cualquier otra que consideres valida(si asi lo consideras tambien), gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> sin embargo he visto que la mayoría de desarrollos mas profesionales o
> de personas con mayor experiencia retornan IEnumerable vs IQueryable

Eso es un tema de abstracción. Tanto `IEnumerable` como `IQuerable` son interfaces y al retornar o recibir  tipos de interfaz se hace que el código sea más desacoplado lo que es mejor. Por eso lo ves en programadores mas experimentados ya que ellos tienen más conocimiento de los principios de diseño de software.

No hay problema que por el momento uses `List` para todo. Con el tiempo y el estudio irás entendiendo los conceptos de diseño hasta que ya sepas por qué devolver un `IEnumerable` o un `IQuerable`. De todas formas `List` implementa la interfaz `IEnumerable` y otras tantas interfaces más así que `List` es a su vez un `IEnumerable` en su versión más genérica.

Te agrego un ejemplo sencillo de abstracción con interfaces:

En el siguiente código hay un método llamado `DemoInterface(MyInterface obj)` el cual recibe cualquier objeto que implemente la interfaz `MyInterface` (como lo haría un programador más experimentado), fíjate como recibe instancias de `MyClass1` y `MyClass2`, ese método está desacoplado, lo que es bueno.

Caso contrario el método `DemoClass(MyClass1 obj)` (como lo haría un programador con menos experiencia)  está acoplado a un tipo concreto de objeto lo cual no es recomendable.

Aunque el ejemplo no usa `IEnumerable` ni `IQuerable` el principio es el mismo.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myClass1 = new MyClass1();
            var myClass2 = new MyClass2();

            // este método está acoplado a una clase en específico
            // solo permite objetos de la clase MyClass1
            DemoClass(myClass2);

            // recibe cualquier tipo de objeto que implemente la interfaz
            // MyInterface eso permite que este método no dependa de una clase concreta
            DemoInterface(myClass1);
            DemoInterface(myClass2);
        }

        static void DemoClass(MyClass1 obj){}
        static void DemoInterface(MyInterface obj){}
    }

    public interface MyInterface
    {
        void Hola();
    }

    public class MyClass1 : MyInterface
    {
        public void Hola()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hola");
        }
    }
    public class MyClass2 : MyInterface
    {
        public void Hola()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hola");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Esto es una explicación en mi parecer errónea. No es mejor ni peor usar un `List<T>` o `IList<T>` que un `IEnumerable<T>` o un `IQueryable<T>`. Cada uno es una clase o interfaz diferente que indican una intención especifica e implícitamente como debe usarse o que esperar. Por ejemplo `List<T>` o `IList<T>` se refieren a métodos que devuelven inmediatamente los datos, mientras que `IEnumerable<T>` solo hace mención a que es "recorrible", generalmente se asume que la ejecución es diferida. Por otro lado `IQueryable<T>` representa un árbol de expresiones (AST) de un query.

Answer (score 2):

Los **IEnumerable** se deberían emplear en consultas de objetos en memoria, como listas y arreglos, por ejemplo. Ahora bien si nuestra consulta **Linq** fuese a una base de datos y usáramos un **IEnumerable**, lo que sucedería es que se traerían de la base de datos todos los registros, estos se cargarían en memoria y sería entonces donde se aplicarían los filtros de la consulta, dígase lo que va en el **Where**. Esto es ineficiente, ya que estaríamos gastando más memoria de la necesaria.

Por otra parte, decir que los **IQueryables** implementan la **Interfaz IEnumerable**, por tanto todo lo que se hace con un **IEnumerable** se puede hacer con **IQueryable**. El **IQueryable** ejecuta los filtros en el mismo servidor de base de datos(estaría en una máquina diferente a la nuestra), y trae los datos ya filtrados a nuestra computadora.

Resumen, usar **IEnumerable** para consultas locales y **IQueryable** para consultas remotas. Hay más diferencias, pero esta a mi entender es la más importante.

Usando **IEnumerable**:

```
IEnumerable<Estudiante> list = dbContext.Estudiantes.Where(e => e.Nota > 80);
```

Se traerían todos los registros de la **tabla Estudiante** se cargarían en la memoria local y entonces aquí sería donde se ejecutaría el **Where**.

Usando **IQueryable**:

```
IQueryable<Estudiante> list = dbContext.Estudiantes.Where(e => e.Nota > 80);
```

En la misma base de datos se ejecuta el **Where** y los registros vienen ya filtrados a nuestra computadora.

Comment: Hola Japv, me queda mas clara la idea. muchas gracias por los ejemplos, entonces, si voy a traer datos de alguna fuente remota, debería usar IQueryable<> ya que ejecuta el query de forma completa y tengo entendido que se ejecuta unicamente cuando lo implemento o lo itero, pudiendo pasar por varios estados:
Ej: IQueryable<estudiante> list1 = dbContext.Estudiantes.Where(e=>e.Nota>80);
list1.OrderBy(O => O.Nota);
List<estudiante> listaFInal = list1.Where(c => c.Name.Contains("j")); -> AQUI ya se ejecuta el query, NO antes, agregando los WHERE, ORDERBY al query.

Comment: Olvidé mencionar algo, en esta instrucción: IEnumerable<estudiante> list = dbContext.Estudiantes.Where(e=>e.Nota>80);  a pesar de estar el SELECT y el WHERE en la misma linea, es decir, siendo una misma instrucción, aún así esta trayendo TODOS los registros a la pila para luego filtrarlos ?

Comment: Porque te complicas tanto, es sencillo IQueryable para trabajar con datos externos y que el procesamiento se haga del lado del servidor, de modo que tu ya recibas los datos filtrados y IEnumerable para trabajar con listas, arreglos y colecciones en memoria

Comment: La idea es buena pero la explicación también es errónea. Ambas expresiones del lado derecho del igual son iguales por lo que se ejecutan exactamente de la misma manera. Cuando se les enumere ambos ejecutarán el filtro en la BD y no en memoria. Esto se debe a que ambos tienen el `.Where()` sobre `.Estudiantes` que es un `IDbSet` (que implementa tanto `IQueryable<T>` como `IEnumerable<T>`) . Simplemente el resultado (Otro IQueryable<T> que por cierto también `IEnumerable<T>`) será almacenado en una varible de uno u otro tipo.

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-the-difference-between-ienumerable-and-iqueryable-in-chash mira la parte que dice que IEnumerable selecciona todos los registros de la bd, los lleva a la memoria y es en memoria donde se hacen los filtros, mira también la parte en que dice que IQueryable ejecuta la consulta  en la bd, ahí mismo hace el filtro y carga en memoria los datos ya filtrados, o sea exactamente lo que digo yo, que IQueryable use árboles de expresión no afecta en nada mi respuesta, por favor vuelve a leer mi respuesta y revisa el voto que me diste, gracias y saludos

Comment: En primer lugar una página llamada tutorialspoint.com donde cualquiera puede subir el tutorial que sea me inspira 0 confianza, siempre recurre a la documentación oficial.  El artículo contiene muchos errores e imprecisiones que no vale la pena mencionar ahora. En segundo lugar el mismo artículo menciona que salvo por el `top 1` ambos SQL generados contienen el WHERE por lo que el filtro se ejecuta en BD y no en memoria.

Comment: La diferencia de porque uno tiene top y el otro no es que el `Take` se está ejecutando sobre el `IQueryable` o `IEnumerable` a diferencia del `Where` que en ambos casos está sober el `DbSet`. Y finalmente te recomiendo que lo pruebes tu mismo y te convenzas.

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz ya estuve investigando y me quedo todo mas claro, tus dos ultimos comentarios tambien me aclararon mas, gracias y saludos, mas tarde mejoro mi respuesta