# ¿Qué es mas eficiente iQueriable, iEnumerable o List y para que se usa cada tipo?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

tengo esa duda, cual es mas eficiente ante rendimiento o tarda menos en realizar la consulta y en que casos se debe de utilizar un tipo u otro?

Gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Son 3 cosas distintas.. muy distintas... la pregunta seria mas eficiente para que?

Comment: de paso.. mira aca: https://stackoverflow.com/q/252785/73749.. igual list no tiene absolutamente nada que ver...

Comment: Entra aki https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/432645/ienumerable-vs-iqueryable-vs-list/432684#432684